# Can't browse to folders of my website

Tags: web-hosting

Basically, I have a few subfolders that I would like to access and I can't seem to access them unless their is a `index.php/html` is located in that file. How do I enable it so that I can access any file within the folder without their being a index page?

I am hosting at GoDaddy, if that makes any difference (and it is a Linux server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are expecting to see a directory listing of the files in that folder? This is a feature of the webserver and is often disabled by default for security reasons - since sites don't generally want users to be able to simply browse the files on their server.

On Apache this is controlled by [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) and you should be able to enable directory indexes with the following directive in .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
```

Various other directives can be specified in order to customise the formatting.

---

*However, I may have misunderstood(?), as your question seems to contradict what I would have expected to be normal behaviour...*

> I can't seem to access them **unless** their is a `index.php/html` is located in that file.

If there is an `index.php/html` file in a folder you are trying to view then you won't see a directory index, you will see the `index.php` file instead (which seems to be the opposite to what you state above).

> How do I enable it so that I can access any file within the folder without their being a index page?

To access any file within the folder you simply need to specify the full URL of that file, this is irrespective of whether you have an `index.php` document or not and is certainly necessary when you do (rather than when you do not, which again seems to be the opposite to what you have stated).